# Python Open CV error : Name error: name images is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to change the color of the image from RGB to grayscale using openCV, Python

My python code is as follows:

```
import cv2 ;
import numpy ;
img = cv2.imread(images/aiims.png) ;
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) ;
cv2.imshow('Original Image', img) ;
cv2.imshow('Gray Image', gray) ;
```

The Error That I am getting is :

> File "test.py", line 11, in
>   
>       img = cv2.imread(images/aiims.png) ; NameError: name 'images' is not defined

I have already installed `opencv` and `numpy`.

I have the image in the image folder in the same directory,
Please tell me if there is any flaw in my code, as I am very new to Python.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems. To read in an image, you must place the path in quotes. Another problem is that your program is immediately closing after it displays an image. That's why the the image doesn't show. You need to add in [`cv2.waitKey()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563). From the docs

> Its argument is the time in milliseconds. The function waits for specified milliseconds for any keyboard event. If you press any key in that time, the program continues. If 0 is passed, it waits indefinitely for a key stroke.

So in your case to display the image indefinitely, just pass in `0`.

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("images/aiims.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Original Image', img)
cv2.imshow('Gray Image', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

You can also read in a grayscale directly like this

```
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread("images/aiims.png", 0)
cv2.imshow('Gray Image', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use and mention path in "" quotes

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the above code line that you mentioned

Comment: aur use import Image

Comment: I added the path in quotes, now my program runs but in run time i am not able to see any image . the two windows opens but they does not respond. and not able to see any image in both the windows

Comment: if you can . please run the above code in your system, and please tell me If and what is the problem is my code. . Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 window because you menstion 2 time show. Its working . but at show time you not correctly show image .. -> try this  cv2.imshow('image',img)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195896/discussion-between-alkesh-mahajan-and-abnit-chauhan).